# Creating a text file using keys from dictionary with multiple values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, join, file-io

I've been working on compiling information for this dictionary:

```py
{'Uranus': ['2750', '3000', '2880'],
'Mercury': ['46', '70', '57'],
'Earth': ['147', '152', '150'],
'Venus': ['107', '109', '108'],
'Mars': ['205', '249', '228'],
'Saturn': ['1350', '1510', '1430'],
'Jupiter': ['741', '817', '779'],
'Neptune': ['4450', '4550', '4500'],
'Pluto': ['4440', '7380', '5910']}
```

I now am trying to write to a text file with each line being one key, and each key and value separated only by a comma, to produce the following:

```
Uranus,2750,3000,2880
Mercury,46,70,57
Earth,147,152,150
etc
```

## Current code

```py
with open(OUTPUT_FILE, "w") as s:
     for key in sol:
         cap_every_other(key)
         combined = [key, sol[key[:]]]
         complete = ', '.join(combined)
         s.write(complete + '\n')
```

With this though, the value list is sending an error flag for not being a string.
How can I combine these keys and values to match the format? Thanks for the help. I must have rewritten this thing 50 times.

Comment: always best to post the **exact** output and the **exact** error message

Comment: You are trying to join a list that contains a list. Instead maybe use `combined = [key] + sol[key]` to make a single list of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution iterating through the dictionary's keys and values respectively using the in-built [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) method, along with [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

```py
sol = {'Uranus': ['2750', '3000', '2880'],
'Mercury': ['46', '70', '57'],
'Earth': ['147', '152', '150'],
'Venus': ['107', '109', '108'],
'Mars': ['205', '249', '228'],
'Saturn': ['1350', '1510', '1430'],
'Jupiter': ['741', '817', '779'],
'Neptune': ['4450', '4550', '4500'],
'Pluto': ['4440', '7380', '5910']}

with open(OUTPUT_FILE, "w") as s:
    for k, v in sol.items():
        s.write(f"{k},{','.join(v)}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot combine a string in a list the way you do:
either you do.
You can do either
`[key] + item` or `[key, *item]`

you can use `items()` to iterate directly through keys and values

```
 with open(OUTPUT_FILE, "w") as s:
        for key, value in sol.items():
            cap_every_other(key)  # not sure what this line is supposed to do
            complete = ', '.join([key] + value)
            s.write(complete + '\n')
```

Comment: Curious, why do you think `[key, *item]` is less efficient than `[key] + item`?

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but I thought, that decomposing a  list into arguments is less efficient, but probably you're right and it doesn't make a difference. will remove the comment as I don't have time to  compare the byte codes.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) from the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module. You can write each row as a list of items with [`csvwriter.writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow).

```
from csv import writer

data = {
    "Uranus": ["2750", "3000", "2880"],
    "Mercury": ["46", "70", "57"],
    "Earth": ["147", "152", "150"],
    "Venus": ["107", "109", "108"],
    "Mars": ["205", "249", "228"],
    "Saturn": ["1350", "1510", "1430"],
    "Jupiter": ["741", "817", "779"],
    "Neptune": ["4450", "4550", "4500"],
    "Pluto": ["4440", "7380", "5910"],
}

with open("output.csv", mode="w", newline='') as csv_out:
    csv_writer = writer(csv_out)
    for k, v in data.items():
        csv_writer.writerow([k, *v])
```

Or write all the rows at once using a list comprehension and [`csvwriter.writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows).

```
with open("output.csv", mode="w", newline='') as csv_out:
    csv_writer = writer(csv_out)
    csv_writer.writerows([[k, *v] for k, v in data.items()])
```

**output.csv**

```
Uranus,2750,3000,2880
Mercury,46,70,57
Earth,147,152,150
Venus,107,109,108
Mars,205,249,228
Saturn,1350,1510,1430
Jupiter,741,817,779
Neptune,4450,4550,4500
Pluto,4440,7380,5910
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and [`.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

data = your data from question

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')

# save to csv
df.to_csv('data.csv', sep=',', header=False)
```

- Incidentally, having the data in a dataframe will facilitate analysis and graphing.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually construct the output with one line of Python (other than the data, obviously) by using list comprehensions<sup>(a)</sup>:

```
data = {
    "Uranus": ["2750", "3000", "2880"],
    "Mercury": ["46", "70", "57"],
    "Earth": ["147", "152", "150"],
    "Venus": ["107", "109", "108"],
    "Mars": ["205", "249", "228"],
    "Saturn": ["1350", "1510", "1430"],
    "Jupiter": ["741", "817", "779"],
    "Neptune": ["4450", "4550", "4500"],
    "Pluto": ["4440", "7380", "5910"],
}

print("\n".join([f'{planet},{",".join(data[planet])}' for planet in data]))
```

Breaking this expression apart:

- `f'something'` is a Python f-string, where variables and expression can be interpreted within the string itself - for example `f'_{7+4}_'` will give you `'_11_'`;
- `{planet}` within that f-string means just that, the variable `planet` (see below for where this comes from);
- `{",".join(data[planet])}` is a `join` expression within that f-string, that takes *each* element in the list `data[planet]`, and gives you a string separated by commas - for example, the expression `','.join(data['Earth'])` would give you `'147,152,150'`;
- `[... for planet in data]` will construct a list of each of those things above (the planets and their values), one per planet in the `data` collection - this is where the `planet` variable comes from in the above few points;
- finally, `"\n".join(...)` is the outer `join` expression that takes all the planet outputs (for example `Earth,147,152,150`) from the previous point, and creates a string where they're separated by newlines.

Then we just print that string, and you can see it generates the correct data:

```
Uranus,2750,3000,2880
Mercury,46,70,57
Earth,147,152,150
Venus,107,109,108
Mars,205,249,228
Saturn,1350,1510,1430
Jupiter,741,817,779
Neptune,4450,4550,4500
Pluto,4440,7380,5910
```

To get that to your output file rather than just printing it, it's a simple matter of:

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as new_file:
    print("\n".join([f'{planet},{",".join(data[planet])}' for planet in data]), file=new_file)
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This is *fine* with small collections like this, but you *may* want to re-think it if you're storing data on all the roughly hundred billion or so planets in our galaxy. That would be one big string :-)